# Computing the double integral of copula function.

Tags: probability

$C(u,v)$ is a copula function. Are the two following expressions equal? if they are not equal, could you help me to calculate the left expression? thanks very much.
$$ \int_q^1\int_p^1 dC(u,v) =? \int_q^1\int_p^1 \frac{\partial C(u,v)}{\partial u}\frac{\partial C(u,v)}{ \partial v} dudv$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first integral means

$$\int_q^1\int_p^1 dC(u,v) = \int_q^1\int_p^1 \frac{\partial^2 C(u,v)}{\partial u\partial v}\ dudv$$

Comment: I have a copula question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2537170/prove-that-cu-v-left-max-u-theta-v-theta-1-0-right-1-th and was wondering if you would be able to help out with it? Thanks! :)